# Repository not found when uploading project to github

Tags: github

Please guide. I'm uploading project to github, using git command or push/clone method also cannot, already install git. Empty repository is created in github account.

```
echo "# hotelWeb" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/noel020395/hotelWeb.git
git push -u origin main
```

I run these commands in terminal one by one, in the end show error "repo not found"? What should I do?

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Can anyone guide me?